# i can't a create a model in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

when i try to create a model in NodeJS

const mongoose = require ('mongoose');

const User = mongoose.model('User',{
name:{
type:string
},
lastname:{
type:string
},
age: {
type:Number
}

})

module.exports = User;

**errorIS
**
C:\Users\models\user.js:6
type:string
^
ReferenceError: string is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\backend\models\user.js:6:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\moham\Desktop\backend\server.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)

Node.js v18.12.1

Comment: change that `name:{ type:string }` to `name:{ type:String }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is saying that the variable "string" is not defined. In Mongoose, when creating a model, the data types for the fields are typically specified as strings, not by using the JavaScript keyword "string". To fix this, you can change the following line:

```
name:{ type:string }, lastname:{ type:string }
```

to:

```
name:{ type:String }, lastname:{ type:String }
```

This should resolve the "ReferenceError: string is not defined" error.